# Why is multiple imputation not used more widely in Data Science?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I posted this question a few days ago on datascience.SE because I thought it was more relevant there:

[Why is multiple imputation not used more widely in Data Science?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/126439/why-is-multiple-imputation-not-used-more-widely-in-data-science)

> I have a background in statistics. Multiple imputation is very commonly used to handle missing data, and if it is not used it almost always results in serious criticism. Recently I have been interviewing for data scientist roles and so far none of the employers appear to use multiple imputation. A quick search for "multiple imputation" on this site resulted in only 27 matches !

> Of course I understand that using MI requires more time and effort, but is that the only reason why ? For categorical data I can see the appeal of having a "missing" category, but what about numeric data? It appears that mean (or median) imputation is quite common in DS, but in statistics, this very much frowned upon since it is changing the distribution of the data often leading to bias.

However I was mildly surprised to receive rather few responses and those responses were not of high quality (eg. *"...bias not being as much of a problem if your main task is prediction."*).

Therefore I am posting it here as I know we have a lot of great data scientists here on CV. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: There should be much deeper replies, but I have some simple suggestions. The method is complicated and requires detailed study and sometimes specific programming.  Missing data  is a problem that often researchers find variously uninteresting in itself, a nuisance or an embarrassment. Moreover, it doesn't solve the most common single fact about missingness, namely that it's often not random in any defined sense.

Comment: My WAG (wild-a..ed guess): data scientists *do* impute, they just don't call it out especially. Essentially, they see a missing value, they just fill it in with the median or mean, no big deal, and don't waste another thought on it. After all, if they thought about why this might be an issue, they wouldn't be data scientists any more, but statisticians!

Comment: Many statisticians, or statistically-minded researchers, don't self-describe as "data scientists". (As @Stephan Kolassa may be hinting, some data scientists are computer scientists who don't know much statistics, and yes, many statisticians don't know much computer science either.)

Comment: I think it’s more of a problem of an isolationist way of working by some data scientists.  Multiple imputation is now a standard and much needed tool, and I even introduce non-statisticians to it when I teach clinical investigators.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Could you please expand on this “isolationist” way of working?

Comment: I have seen a good many data scientists not study applied statistics and statistical modeling, which puts them at a disadvantage.  Witness the popularity of SMOTE.  No one who studied statistics would change observed data to make the distribution of the dependent variable "balanced".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of people in applied fields do not realize that "traditional" methods for handling missing data (e.g., listwise or pairwise deletion) are actually *more* problematic and rest on stronger assumptions about missing data mechanisms (i.e., missing completely at random data vs. missing at random data) than multiple imputation (MI) or full information maximum likelihood (FIML). This may be one reason why they hesitate to use MI.

In addition, in some fields, people still think that it is like "cheating" to replace missing values with imputed values even though the statistical theory behind the (multiple) imputations is much more sound than behind other approaches such as listwise or pairwise deletion.

Educating people that bias is actually less likely with MI and FIML than with listwise/pairwise deletion (or mean imputation, last observation carried forward, etc.) and that statistical power tends to be higher with MI and FIML may help.

Comment: Can you explain more about how complete case analysis has *stronger* assumptions than MI?

Comment: Listwise deletion requires "missing completely at random" (MCAR) data to work without bias, whereas MI and FIML only require the weaker assumption of "missing at random" (MAR) data. In addition, even under MCAR data, MI and FIML have the advantage of providing greater statistical power than listwise deletion (which uses a reduced sample). See, e.g., Enders, C. K. (2022). Applied missing data analysis (2nd ed.). Guilford Publications.

Comment: I was never quite clear how MI would ameliorate bias under MAR. According to Rubin, Maximum likelihood models like OLS, MAR and MCAR make no difference, but semiparametric would be different. I played with a few scenarios and couldn't identify any bias. But in general, MI is highly effective as an information recovery strategy.

Comment: "MAR" means the information about why scores are missing is in your data (i.e., is contained in other variables). When using MI or FIML, this information is taken into account (thus avoiding or at least reducing bias) whereas it is not taken into account with listwise deletion.

Comment: FIML is not ML on the complete cases but ML integrating over the missing data?

Comment: @AdamO: if your imputation model has more variables than your model of interest, it is quite easy to imagine. For example, suppose you are looking at the univariate distribution of income but 50% of subjects who are unemployed leave income blank. Your "model" of interest ignores employment status, but by using this variable you are able to correct the bias of under representation of unemployed people in your observed incomes.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is:

1. It's an additional effort; depending on the situation it can create quite some work.
2. There is a large number of decisions that need to be made, and for some of these there isn't really a strong guideline that tells people what to do in what situation. All I have read on MICE emphasises that whatever is presented as example or "default" uses something that in a different situation maybe should be done differently. People often shy away from doing things that look too "subjective" or where they have to make decisions and take personal responsibility in situations where they can't refer to clear and simple guidelines.
3. In some cases it may make results look less certain, and the results therefore may be a harder "sell".

Of course from the point of view of appropriate exploration and communication of uncertainty, 3 is not a good reason, and the thing with 2 is that people need to realise that despite all the "hard" decisions, doing *something* is in most situations better than not doing anything, even if somebody later finds that many decisions that are actually made in a specific situation could be improved.

PS: When writing "not doing anything" I have some standard actions in mind such as deleting all cases with missings, or mean imputation. These are indeed just as "subjective" (there's nothing objective about choosing to avoid a course of action because it requires more decisions) and normally worse; particularly they don't allow a quantification of uncertainty coming from the treatment of missing values, which we should be keen on as statisticians.

Comment: Indeed, however, many overlook that simply excluding all cases with missing data is equally subjective.

Comment: +1 but a thing that puzzles me is that a controversial procedure like SMOTE (https://academic.oup.com/jamia/article/29/9/1525/6605096) also takes additional effort and requires taking the decision to use it. Yet, it seems to be somehow popular among (some) data scientists. So I'm wondering if the difficulty or uncertainty of a given procedure is sufficient to explain its (un)popularity.

Comment: @J-J-J SMOTE is even less popular than MICE around my quarters, but that may be different elsewhere. There are also social processes at work, influential people leading big groups, and people with marketing talent and means that make/keep something fashionable. I don't think there are substantial reasons in all such cases.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the context. In many prediction situations, there is actually a lot of information in missingness and even missigness at random does not apply (never mind missingness completely at random), because it might indicate something has not happened/attitudes of people/"having something to hide"/newness of something (e.g. missing price of last ordered product because customer has never ordered something, refusal to answer a question might indicate something, lack of publicly available information on something might indicate something etc.). For that reason it is often popular to have a flag for missingness and then some simple imputation on the variable that is missing (which has also been suggested to perform decently for dealing with missing baseline information when comparing treatments in randomized clinical trials, where one might normally be tempted to use multiple imputation) in order to capture the fact that something is missing. That would be a good reason to prefer something else over multiple imputation, but you could of course speculate that multiple imputation in addition to a missingness indicator might still be a good idea.

Additionally, you might worry that a multivariate normal (or even worse MI by chained equations) imputation model is insufficiently complex to appropriately impute missing values due to non-linearities and/or complex interactions. Some standard implementations of these approach may also struggle to adequately deal with some non-standard data types like high cardinality categorical data, ordered categorical data, count data etc. - although one can of course extend MI to these settings. Whether that's a good reason not to do it (or whether you should look for a MI method that allows for more complexity) depends on your particular case.

In settings were missingness at random is a sensible assumption and a multiple imputation model you can use is sufficiently complex, it may very well be a good idea to do MI and I suspect it's underutilized. That's probably due to several factors:

1. No good tooling for combining multiple imputation with standard machine learning workflows. E.g. do you really need to manually code up that you fit a ML model for every imputation, then a apply imputation to all new validation/test data coherent with each imputed dataset, followed by the ML model fit on that? See also the next point and also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517400/machine-learning-on-mice-imputed-data/542179#542179) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613332/multiple-imputation-for-prediction/613345#613345))
2. It's time consuming, because you currently need to fit one model per imputed dataset, although there might be alternative like sampling an imputed dataset for each tree in a xgboost model or something like that (but I'm not aware of any software that support doing that).
3. Several MI tools don't actually support applying the imputation model to new unseen data (most are intended for when you have all data at once and some is partially missing), especially in a way that makes them coherent (in terms of having the same underlying parameters used for imputed training dataset 1 and imputed validation/testing dataset 1 etc.).
4. A lot of things in the data science/ML space come from the computer science community, while multiple imputation is more from the statistics community, so people may just not be familiar with the approach.
5. I'm not aware that anyone has done any investigation into MI + ML and shown that it helps a lot in some situations. I've done a little bit of simulation that actually suggests that the default method of imputation in xgboost is actually really hard to beat with MI, but I don't want to exaggerate the implications of a small simulation study. I suspect one promising situation could be one where you have censored observations where you e.g. only know that income is >10,000 USD/month  (where it seems conceivable that MI could beat setting the value to 10,000 and having an extra flag for >10,000).

Answer (score 4):

My anecdotal experience from a particular type of data: it didn't perform very well.

The first time I learned about matrix completion (a somewhat dated method that can impute missing values), I thought this was already a solved problem due to multiple imputation. To demonstrate this, I generated some data and applied both methods. Much to my surprise, MI took much longer *and* the imputed values were much less accurate, even when using the mean imputed value.

After some thought, I'm pretty certain the reason for this was that in the way I generated the data, the predictors have noise on top of them. Matrix completion is a method that accounts for error in the predictors, vanilla regression does not.

Of course, this is data generated by the matrix completion model so naturally matrix completion should do quite well. And we can replace simple regression models with more complex models. But to my point, it's definitely not a forgone conclusion that MI is an optimal (or even near optimal) approach.